# Django 2.0 - Rendering wrong template (with no error)

Tags: django-templates, django-2.0

I'm trying to load a template `visit_form.html` which is a DetailView with a form within it. Each time I click on a link from `main.html` the wrong template gets loaded -> `main_detail.html`. I have cleared browser cache, invalidated caches.

The goal is to have the `MainVisitDisplay` render the `visit_form.html`, but all I get is the  `main_detail.html`. It throws an error for  `main_detail.html` when I change the location of the  `main_detail.html` template, and throws a "TemplateDoesNotExist" error, looking for the `main_detail.html` template.

My MWE is:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('main/', views.MainListView.as_view(), name='main'),
    path('main/<int:pk>/', views.MainDetailView.as_view(), name='main_detail'),
    path('visit/add/<int:pk>/', views.MainVisitDisplay.as_view(), name='visit_form'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class MainVisitDisplay(DetailView):
    model = Main
    template = "visit_form.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = VisitForm()
        return context


class MainDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = "clincher/main_detail.html"
    model = Main
```

**main.html (template) url**

```
{% url 'clincher:visit_form' main.id %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a really simple. use `template_name = "template_name.html"` NOT `template = "template_name.html`. Not sure why it kept rendering the other templates. Also, apparently, Django 2.0 does not cache templates, but feel free to confirm or deny this.